# How to retrive workitem IDs ? to use it in WorkItems list API

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I need to get a list of workitems under my projects .Treid using this API call

https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems?ids={ids}&api-version=5.0

it has a mandatory parameter as IDs so i need to find the IDs of workitems.

Can someone guide me on how to get the list of IDs ? or any APIs available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do this using WIQL instead. Here is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0). The response will contain a list of work items.

[WIQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops) is quite power query language. You can achieve much more with it than with just plain REST API calls.